# 403 Error When Making Twitter Search API Call

Tags: api, google-chrome, search, twitter

Today, my script stopped working in Chrome, and now I get a 403 Forbidden, or a 400 Bad Request. This only happens in Chrome, and only with my Twitter Search API call:

```
var url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=myquery&include_entities=true&callback=?";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'testCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",    
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
```

I've seen some similar complaints here and on other forums, but never an explanation that makes sense adn certainly not a solution. How can this be a Chrome-only error. If you paste the search query url into location bar, the feed is returned.

I'm at a loss, and being so close to launching my app, a little worried.

**EDIT:** The Error is now 400 and is in ALL browsers. From what I've learned, this is probably something to do with Twitter deprecating v.1 of their API.

Comment: This has happened to me today to. I cannot find an explanation, and my only guess is that it might have to do with an update to Chrome. All other browsers behave fine, with Chrome throwing a 403. Any progress/solution?

Answer (score 1):

Check your network activity - Chrome is automatically converting your HTTP requests to HTTPS requests. Probably the best way to get around this is to route your request through a proxy:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-cross-domain-ajax-request-with-yql-and-jquery/

I read somewhere  Twitter is disabling anonymous AJAX requests completely in about a month as part of their API 1.0 deprecation plan. All Search API request will need to be made with an application authentication token.

Answer (score 0):

This happened here too. Yesterday it was working correctly on all browsers, today we're getting 403 from search calls in Chrome (other browsers are still working). rate_limit_status.json is returning correctly on Chrome though. Tried to change the protocol from http to https on search requests but it didn't help. Currently using jTweetsAnywhere jquery plugin to fetch the twitter feeds. As I debugged more I noticed that when I remove the callback parameter from the query, I get the response that I was after.

Edit: today its working here with Chrome again..

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old but for anyone searching for an answer it is to do with the new Twitter API, there's a posted explanation with a note about making it work again in the future here: http://thomasbillenstein.com/jTweetsAnywhere/